# RDS PostgresSQL

Tags: amazon-rds, temporary-tables

I have to replicate a database as close to a production db as possible.

The production DB is 300gb, in my demo rds db in my personal account I will most likely select roughly 150gb but is there anyway I can populate it with a dummy table?
Does rds table examples exist anywhere please?

Basically I am trying to use fault injection simulator to see how quickly the db failovers to the standby instance.

Thanks